# I have a problem with the If statement on text with def time

Tags: python, if-statement, time, pygame

I am a beginner using Python 3.7 and just can't def time correctly editing a pygame. I want to show some text if the score of a game > 100, and I know I can't use "print" instead on "text", because it shows on the program bar, not in the program itself (like I'd see)

I already tried to def time(score, text):
and put only def time():

Like this:

```
import sys
import pygame
import time

def time():
    time.sleep(5)
        if score > 100:
        text = "X"
        label = myFont.render(text, 1, WHITE)
        screen.blit(label, (WIDTH-100, HEIGHT-50))
```

And:

```
import sys
import pygame
import time

def time(score, text):
    time.sleep(5)
        if score > 100:
        text = "X"
        label = myFont.render(text, 1, WHITE)
        screen.blit(label, (WIDTH-100, HEIGHT-50))
```

Comment: Are all the indentations after `def time()` and `if` correct?

Comment: You mean the space after the codes?

Comment: Yes, the space before the code

Comment: If you mean it, yes

Comment: Your function `time` overwrites your import `time`. Choose an other name.

Comment: Then, yes......

Comment: Because your code snippet doesn't show that

Comment: Sorry then, i did it on the program i'm using
https://imgur.com/zH5bSXE

Comment: @NatalieBach Indentation is still wrong like that, remove the indentation before the if-statement so it has the same indentation as `time.sleep(5)`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it, thanks

Comment: @funie200 the program is now running, but it did not shows the "text" yet

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? Like where you call the `time` function and what parameters you give it.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation of your if-statement is wrong. You need to have it on the same level as `time.sleep(5)`, try this:

```
def time(score, text):
    time.sleep(5)
    if score > 100:
        text = "X"
        label = myFont.render(text, 1, WHITE)
        screen.blit(label, (WIDTH-100, HEIGHT-50))
```

Comment: I'd tried this, and it's running but not showing the "text". (It does not seems to be a problem for width and height, because I did this numbers on a code before it and worked.)